# Does DBCursor.getServerAddress work as I expect?

Tags: java, mongodb, database-replication

I expect  [getServerAddress](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#getServerAddress%28%29) to return the address of the Mongo server (one of replica set nodes), which actually handles the query.

I am logging output of [getServerAddress](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#getServerAddress%28%29) and see only the *primary* address although I am *pretty sure* that some queries are handled by *secondary*.

I am a little bit confused since I see queries (having set `profillingLevel`) in the *secondary* while [getServerAddress](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#getServerAddress%28%29) returns the *primary*. Maybe I am mistaken though ...

Can it be a bug in the API ? Does anybody encounter such a problem ? Is it possible that [getServerAddress](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#getServerAddress%28%29) always returns the *primary* while some queries are  actually handled by *secondaries* ?

Comment: You need to specify your readPrefernce as [secondaryPreffered](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#secondaryPreferred) and even so there may be a [tag set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-tag-sets) having an effect on this. See the docs. This information is missing from your question. So we need to know more about your configuration in order to answer.

Comment: My question is about the API. I just want to know if the API works exactly as I expect. That is, it always return the address of the node, which actually handles the query. I am confused because the API and profiling show different things but I maybe mistaken though ...

Comment: On the second thought I probably should rephrase the question.

Comment: And my comment was about, "Unles you **include** information on what your *readPreference*, server configuration, possible tagsets are within your question no-one can comment on the behavior you are seeing in your calls. The API should respond to what is **actually** happening.

Comment: Well, the client uses _nearest_, the primary is definitely not the nearest server (located in another data center, ping checked), and there is no tags.

Comment: The "nearest" read preference is broken in subtle ways.  It doesn't always do what you expect it to do.  You'd be better off not relying on it.

Comment: @evanchooly Oh, it's very interesting indeed ! Our application _fully_ relies on `nearest` now. And that's probably the reason I am troubleshooting it now. Could you please explain (or give examples) how it is broken ? Any pointer to the relevant docs or source in github can be helpful too.

Comment: You'd have to talk to our solutions guys to get the full story but nearest isn't always geographically nearest.  and it's not always the best choice perf wise as I understand it.

Comment: @evanchooly Thanks again. Who is that guy ? :) maybe I can contact him.

Comment: Here are the docs that cover some of the gotchas.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#nearest  If you're not having any issues, I wouldn't worry about it overly much.  If you are, I'd suggest filing a support ticket if you have a support contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect getServerAddress to return the address of the Mongo server (one of replica set nodes), which actually handles the query.

This expectation should be correct: [DBCursor.java:getServerAddress()](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/2.11.x/src/main/com/mongodb/DBCursor.java#L630) returns the host value for the current cursor.

> I am logging output of getServerAddress and see only the primary address although I am pretty sure that some queries are handled by secondary.

By default all queries go the primary of the replica set. If you have not explicitly specified any [secondary read preferences](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-replica-set-semantics/#read-preferences-and-tagging) in your application code, the queries on the secondary are coming from another source.

Since you mention using *nearest* read preference in comments on the question, read queries should favour a nearest (by network latency) member of the replica set. The nearest members can be either secondaries or the primary.

The MongoDB manual has more information on [Member Selection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference-mechanics/#replica-set-read-preference-behavior-nearest) for read preferences.

#### Checking the source of queries

You have several options to check the source of queries:

- As a quick check, run `mongostat --discover` to watch read activity across your replica set to see if there is actually secondary read activity outside of replication. Alternatively, you could also view this history through a monitoring service such as the free [MongoDB Management Service](https://mms.mongodb.com/) (MMS).
- Check your server logs on the secondaries for connections from your app server IP(s). Unless you have set [`--quiet` logging mode](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.quiet), you should see new connections logged similar to:

  > [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53548 #1234 (29 connections now open)
- Login to your secondaries and run [db.currentOp()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/); you should see queries from your application server (as identified by the `client` IP in the currentOp info).

Comment: Thank you for the deep and detailed answer. It is _really_ helpful. I am new at `Mongo` and trying to resolve several issues we have with a `Mongo`-based application in production.

Comment: @Michael: Definitely ask more questions if you're unsure. Lots to learn, but there is a helpful community and support from MongoDB, Inc (where I currently work :). FYI, there is also a [mongodb-user discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user) if you have questions which don't fit well into the Q&A format for StackExchange sites. MongoDB team members are active in both forums. You may also want to check if there is an active [MongoDB User Group (MUG)](http://www.mongodb.com/user-groups-mongodb) near you; there's a "March Madness" tour with lots of visiting engineers!

Comment: Thank you again. I will ask more questions soon :))